# How to count the number of attributes whose value is lager than 0 in Selenium Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium Python to count the number of attributes.

The html code is here:

```
<div id="leftw">
<a class="cat "  cid="1">BEVERAGE</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="8">APPS</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="2">SOUPS</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="9">SALADS</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="3">SANDWICHES</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="10">COMBOS</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="4">ENTREES</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="11">PIZZA</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="5">CALZONE</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="12">STROMBOLI</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="6">PASTRIES</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="13">DESSERTS</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="7">BREAD</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="14">SIDES</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="15">MEAT BY POUND</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="18">Kids Meal</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="19">MISC</a>
<a class="cat "  cid="0" ></a>
</div>
```

I want to count the **a** tag number whose **cid** **value** is not equal to **0**.Because there is no value in a tag whose **cid** value equal **0**.

if I run:

```
count_category = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#leftw .cat"))
```

I can only get the total number of all a tags. But I want to exclude the a tag whose cid value equals 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following CSS selector which exclude cid='0'

```
count_category = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#leftw >a.cat:not([cid='0'])"))
```

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537965/how-to-handle-alert-or-pop-up-boxes-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 1):

can you try this?

```
count_category = len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[@id="lefw"]/a[not(@cid="0")]'))
```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer,since I'm using css selector,so just copied the answer below yours,and it simply works,so I chose that one.But I really know your code will works too.Really appreciate!

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537965/how-to-handle-alert-or-pop-up-boxes-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a pseudoselector :not to exclude a situation when an attribute cid equals to 0:

```
count_category = len(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#leftw .cat:not([cid='0'])"))
```

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537965/how-to-handle-alert-or-pop-up-boxes-in-selenium-python

Answer (score 1):

To count the number of attributes whose **cid** attribute value is not equal to **0** using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) Python, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use either of the following  [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div#leftw a.cat:not([cid='0'])")))))
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  print(len(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@id='leftw']//a[@class='cat ' and not(@cid='0')]")))))
  ```

Comment: I really appreciate your answer,since I'm using css selector,so just copied the answer below yours,and it simply works,so I chose that one,but I do believe I will use your code in the future.Thanks again!

Comment: Hi friend,can you help me with this question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59537965/how-to-handle-alert-or-pop-up-boxes-in-selenium-python