# How to handle modal or Pop-up Boxes in Selenium Python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium python to test a resturant pos system.

After click different category menus,there will be about 3 different kinds of pop-up(modal) windows pop out to allow custom to chose items.Different category will pop out different pop-up(modal) windows.

[image]

The category menus code are:

```
<div id="iopopsz" style="display: none">
 <div style="display:flex">
     ...code..
 </div>
</div>


<div id="comboitemsz" class="copt" style="display: none;">
    <div style="display: flex">
        ...code..
</div>
</div>

<div id="mcoption8sz" class="copt" style="display: none;">
        <div style="display: flex">
        ...code..
</div>
</div>
```

As you can see,there is a **style="display: none;"** in each category,if the category is not selected the value of style will keep **display: none**,

once the category is selected,the value of style will change to **display:block**.

Now I need to first check which pop-up(alert) window pop out and then switch to the window to click a item.So what I should do?Any friends can help?

Comment: It doesn't look like you need to switch to any window, but rather find the element/pop-up that has the style attribute equal to display:block.  Once you have that top element, you should be able to find child elements and potentially click on one.  Is this what you're trying to do?

Comment: Is this an alert, or is this a modal? If the dialog has HTML rendering on the page, it's not an alert, it's a modal. The two are handled very differently, so it's important to be specific.

Comment: Thank you for your remain,it is a modal

Comment: @William : If possible share the url?

Comment: @KunduK,it is in our local,so ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `get_attribute("style")` to accomplish what you are trying to do here. From what I can tell, you are not actually working with a true alert -- an alert is a Javascript popup that has no HTML, and can be only accepted or dismissed through the alerts class.

Here's how you can check the `display: none` and `display: block` strings in each element:

```
first_item = driver.find_element_by_id("iopopsz")
style_attr_first_item = first_item.get_attribute("style") # "display: none"

if "display: none;" in style_attr_first_item:
    print("First item is not visible.")
```

Hopefully this will get you started and shows you how to effectively check the `display: none` and `display: block` properties of each element.

Comment: This code will allow you to check the `display: none` and `display: block` properties on each element like you've mentioned in your question -- what additional questions do you have?

Comment: Thank you so much!I have tried!But each time only get:'First item is not visible.',my second and third item,have no response.I will try to figure it out!